# Work with a row in a pandas dataframe without incurring chain indexing (not coping just indexing)

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, series

My data is organized in a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Col1' : [4,5,6,7], 'Col2' : [10,20,30,40], 'Col3' : [100,50,-30,-50], 'Col4' : ['AAA', 'BBB', 'AAA', 'CCC']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index = ['R1','R2','R3','R4'])
```

Which looks like this (only much bigger):

```
    Col1  Col2  Col3 Col4
R1     4    10   100  AAA
R2     5    20    50  BBB
R3     6    30   -30  AAA
R4     7    40   -50  CCC
```

My algorithm loops through this table rows and performs a set of operations.

For cleaness/lazyness sake, I would like to work on a single row at each iteration without typing `df.loc['row index', 'column name']` to get each cell value

I have tried to follow the [right style](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) using for example:

```
row_of_interest = df.loc['R2', :]
```

However, I still get the warning when I do:

```
row_of_interest['Col2'] = row_of_interest['Col2'] + 1000

SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

And it is not working (as I intended) it is making a copy

```
print df

    Col1  Col2  Col3 Col4
R1     4    10   100  AAA
R2     5    20    50  BBB
R3     6    30   -30  AAA
R4     7    40   -50  CCC
```

Any advice on the proper way to do it? Or should I just stick to work with the data frame directly?

Edit 1:

Using the replies provided the warning is removed from the code but the original dataframe is not modified: The "row of interest" `Series` is a copy not part of the original dataframe. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Col1' : [4,5,6,7], 'Col2' : [10,20,30,40], 'Col3' : [100,50,-30,-50], 'Col4' : ['AAA', 'BBB', 'AAA', 'CCC']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index = ['R1','R2','R3','R4'])

row_of_interest         = df.loc['R2']
row_of_interest.is_copy = False
new_cell_value          = row_of_interest['Col2'] + 1000
row_of_interest['Col2'] = new_cell_value

print row_of_interest 

Col1       5
Col2    1020
Col3      50
Col4     BBB
Name: R2, dtype: object

print df

    Col1  Col2  Col3 Col4
R1     4    10   100  AAA
R2     5    20    50  BBB
R3     6    30   -30  AAA
R4     7    40   -50  CCC
```

Edit 2:

This is an example of the functionality I would like to replicate. In python a list of lists looks like:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

Now I can create a "label"

```
b = a[0]
```

And if I change an entry in b:

```
b[0] = 7
```

Both a and b change.

```
print a, b

[[7,2,3],[4,5,6]], [7,2,3]
```

Can this behavior be replicated between a pandas dataframe labeling one of its rows a pandas series?

Comment: check out my edited answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
row_of_interest = df.loc['R2', :]
row_of_interest.is_copy = False
row_of_interest['Col2'] = row_of_interest['Col2'] + 1000
```

Setting `.is_copy = False` is the trick

Edit 2:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Col1' : [4,5,6,7], 'Col2' : [10,20,30,40], 'Col3' : [100,50,-30,-50], 'Col4' : ['AAA', 'BBB', 'AAA', 'CCC']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index = ['R1','R2','R3','R4'])

row_of_interest         = df.loc['R2']
row_of_interest.is_copy = False
new_cell_value          = row_of_interest['Col2'] + 1000
row_of_interest['Col2'] = new_cell_value

print row_of_interest 

df.loc['R2'] = row_of_interest 

print df
```

df:

```
    Col1  Col2  Col3 Col4
R1     4    10   100  AAA
R2     5  1020    50  BBB
R3     6    30   -30  AAA
R4     7    40   -50  CCC
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Indeed, I am not getting the warning now. However, the row of interest is still a copy (I added an example). Do you think I should just replace the new row series in the data frame at the end of the code?

Answer (score 0):

most straight forward way to do this

```
df.loc['R2', 'Col2'] += 1000
df
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Sorry I was not clear enough: In the example I just wanted to modify a cell value within the "row_of_interest" pandas series which would also be reflected on the "df" pandas dataframe.

Comment: Thanks again! That is indeed how it must work. However, the purpose of the question was to avoid typing the ".loc[Row_of_interest" in cases where you are just focused on one row. I have added an example in Edit2 to better illustrate the issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the warning by creating a series with the slice you want to work on:

```
from pandas import Series
row_of_interest = Series(data=df.loc['R2', :])
row_of_interest.loc['Col2'] += 1000
print(row_of_interest)
```

Results in:

```
Col1       5
Col2    1020
Col3      50
Col4     BBB
Name: R2, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Your solution does indeed avoid the warning. However, when I modify the row_of_interest the original dataframe remains unchanged. How would you do it? Would you just replace the old row with the new one at the end of the code?