# How to set the value of a certain field in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have a pandas dataframe like so:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'col2': ['','','','']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

and for some reason, I must loop over all its rows and give `col2` a certain value. My loop is now in `i=1` and `col2` should be `'Check!'`.

Easy, it seems, just

```
df.iloc[i]['col2']='Check'
```

however, this throws a warning, and [a link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) and it seems like this is warranted, since `df.iloc[i]['col2']` just returns my empy `''` instead of the `'Check!'` it should.

Almost the same question is asked (and solved) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40138090/work-with-a-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe-without-incurring-chain-indexing-not-copi), however, the key `.is_copy` command is now deprecated, it appears (I don't get the error everytime, weird…), thus I'm hesitant to use it.

So

```
ri = df.iloc[i]
ri.is_copy = False
newval = 'Check!'
ri['col2']=newval
df.iloc[i]=ri
```

works and is nice and simple, but apparently, it will soon cease to work, so this is not optimal.

**EDIT**

Maybe it makes sense to have the warning in the question, in order to make it more clear and increase its googleability:

```
In [1]: df.iloc[i]['col2']='Check'
Out[1]: /some/path/ipython:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is necessary set by positions by [`DataFrame.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html), but necessary get position by column by [`get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
i = 1
df.iat[i, df.columns.get_loc('col2')]='Check'
#slowier
#df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc('col2')]='Check'
```

Or set by labels with [`DataFrame.at`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html):

```
i = 1
df.at[df.index[i], 'col2']='Check'
#slowier
#df.loc[df.index[i], 'col2']='Check'
```

For default RangeIndex:

```
df.at[i, 'col2']='Check'
```

---

```
print (df)
   col1   col2
0     1       
1     2  Check
2     3       
3     4
```

Comment: Looks good! I'll play around with it a bit so that I really understand it and see if it works for my real data before accepting, though.